# How to grows up a div height with a table that has your rows added dynamically? 

Tags: html, css

I have a div `main` that has a table `grid`. This table has your rows added dynamically. So, the problem is, when i add a row to the table `grid` the height of the table grows up, but the height of the div `main` no. Thus the table is staying in front of the footer content. What i have to add in css or in html to enforce the height of the div `main` grows up with the height of th table `grid`?

The code and the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/BBcsB/8/

The problem is in the fieldset here:

```
fieldset
{
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 0px 20px 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

So, when i remove the `display: inline-block;` works fine, but the fieldset is large, taking the entire div width and height. How can i solve the problem and stay with the fieldset surrounding the elements inside it?

Comment: Is your main-div positioned absolutely? Because the height of the div should normally follow the height of the table (unless you specified an exact size for the div ofcourse)

Comment: Nope. I add the css now.

Comment: As Thomas said, unless you explicitly state the height of an object it will expand to contain its children automatically. Strange that you're nesting tables within divs of table cells though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I put `main` and `footer` divs to `float: left` and `width: 100%` and `fieldset` to `float: left` too, and remove the `display: inline-block` of `fieldset`.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BBcsB/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
.div_that_contains_the_table
{
height: auto; overflow: hidden;
}
```

It should works, but I haven't tryed so if there are problems tell me.

Comment: This doesn't work. The content that is overflowing is staying now in a "hole" in end of the div `main`, and it is staying hidden.

Comment: So probably I didn't understand your problem. Can you paste some code?

Comment: Ok, wait a minute. I 'll paste.

Comment: Done. I forgot that i had another div called `divGrid` but i think that it won't interfere...

Comment: If you edit html code adding more rows to the table, it works. The problem could be in PHP code. Try it, I've just copied your code and added more lines.

Comment: Have you add dynamically throught javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly clearing your `#main` div with your `<br clear="all" />` breakline (`clear="all`"???, try this:

```
#main:before, #main:after {
 content:"";
 display:table;
 zoom:1; /*ie fix*/
}

#main:after {
 clear:both;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work neither. And the `<br clear="all" />` was a friend of mine that said to use...

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni I don't understand, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PZQJu/) is a demo without my fix and my css, and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PZQJu/1/) is a demo with my fix and your css, everything works fine. Also, that break line was supposed to be formatted as `<br style="clear:both;" />`.

Comment: I don't understand as well, because i get all code generated (in ie), all css, all js, put in a new html page, alone... and everything works. But when i run throught visual studio 2010 (is a asp.net mvc 3 project) this doesn't work. But the strange behavior is: i get all the code generated (in ie) by my project like i said... how is this possible?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni I suggest you break down your current HTML structure and start again. Semantically it is quite lacking and full of wholes, so starting anew might fix the issue.

Comment: Talking about the html, what do you suggest?

Comment: I found the problem! The problem is in the question.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni I'd suggest rewriting your main container, it appears that you're nesting a table within a table as a container of sorts that you can easily rewrite as a div.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni Oh, great, what was it?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni would have to look at your current setup, but try this: instead of `display:inline-block` try `float:left;`, if that doesn't work then post your HTML with the position of your fielset intact, we're guessing at this point as to what your issue is.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni I see your demo, can you describe your issue? Your table grows with each new table row added as expected.

Comment: Well, i solved, like i post the answer. But the problem was that the table was in front of the footer.